# Why do we need 'template <class T>' before implementing all templated class methods

Tags: c++, templates

If we have a standard class:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    int fooVar = 10;
    int getFooVar();
}
```

The implementation for `getFooVar()` would be:

```
   int Foo::getFooVar() {
       return fooVar;
   }
```

But in a templated class:

```
template <class T>
class Bar {
  public:
    int barVar = 10;
    int getBarVar();
}
```

The implementation for `getBarVar()` must be:

```
template <class T>
int Bar<T>::getBarVar(){
   return barVar();
}
```

Why must we have the `template <class T>` line before the function implementation of `getBarVar` and `Bar<T>::` (as opposed to just Bar::), considering the fact that the function doesn't use any templated variables?

Comment: I think mostly because the compiler needs to know for which types of `Bar` the function is implemented. If you have a function that adds up member variables but then declare your template with something that does not support arithmetics, the function would fail.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer to this question boils down to "because the standard says so". You could ask "why is there no syntactic sugar for this case" but that's quite opinion-based I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bar` itself is a template, as the other answers said.

But let's now assume that you don't need it, after all, you specified this, and I added another template argument:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Bar
{
    void something();
};
```

Why:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void Bar<T1, T2>::something(){}
```

And not:

```
void Bar::something(){}
```

What would happen if you wanted to specialize your implementation for one type T1, but not the other one? You would need to add that information. And that's where this `template` declaration comes into play and why you also need it for the general implementation (IMHO).

```
template<typename T>
void Bar<T, int>::something(){}
```

Comment: sorry, nitpick, but imho you are feeding the confusion: "The class itself is a template". `Bar` is a template (or class template) and `Bar<T>` is a class. A class is not a template.

Comment: @user463035818 Indeed, I'll change the names.

Answer (score 6):

You need it because `Bar` is not a class, it's a *template*. `Bar<T>` is the class.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate the class, the compiler checks if implementations are there. But at the time you write the code, the final type (i.e. the instantiated type) is not known.

Hence the compiler instantiates the definitions for you, and if the compiler should instantiate something it needs to be templated.

Answer (score 0):

Any answer to this question boils down to "because the standard says so". However, instead of reciting standardese, let's examine what else is **forbidden** (because the errors help us understand what the language expects). The "single template" case is exhausted pretty quickly, so let's consider the following:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    template<class X>
    void foo(X);
};
```

Maybe we can use a single template argument for both?

```
template<class U>
void A<U>::foo(U u)
{
    return;
}
```

> ```
> error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' does not match any declaration in 'A<T>'
> ```

No, we cannot. Well, maybe like this?

```
template<class U>
void A<U>::foo<U>(U u)
{
    return;
}
```

> ```
> error: cannot specialize a member of an unspecialized template
> ```

No. And this?

```
template<class U, class V>
void A<U>::foo(V u)
{
    return;
}
```

> ```
> error: too many template parameters in template redeclaration
> ```

How about using a default to emulate the matching?

```
template<class U>
template<class V = U>
void A<U>::foo(V u)
{
    return;
}
```

> ```
> error: cannot add a default template argument to the definition of a member of a class template
> ```

Clearly, the compiler is worried about matching the **declaration**. That's because the compiler doesn't match template definitions to specific calls (as one might be used to from a functional language) but to the template declaration. (Code so far [here](https://godbolt.org/z/HzG09J)).

So on a basic level, the answer is "because the template definition must match the template declaration". This still leaves open the question "why can we not just omit the class template parameters then?" (as far as I can tell no ambiguity for the template can exist so repeating the template parameters does not help) though...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function template declaration

```
tempalte <typename T> 
void foo();
```

now a definition

```
void foo() { std::cout << "Hello World"; }
```

is either a specialization of the above template or an overload. You have to pick either of the two. For example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void foo();

void foo() { std::cout << "overload\n"; }

template <typename T>
void foo() { std::cout << "specialization\n"; }

int main() {
    foo();
    foo<int>();
}
```

Prints:

```
overload
specialization
```

The short answer to your question is: Thats how the rules are, though if you could ommit the `template <typename T>` from a definition of the template, a different way would be required to define an overload.